# DevExpress Gantt Chart

Tags: c#, devexpress

Problem about DevExpress Gantt Chart in C#

When Work is not complete then Y-axis ordering is ok but after the work completed processes move to last position. The problem is Y-axis jumbling .

I'm trying multiple examples but not get right solution .

Comment: "jumbling" - like in _"to mix things together in a confused or untidy way"_ ? [Oxford learner's dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/jumble_1?q=jumbling)

Comment: Can you post an example and how you created it?

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: WinForms Appliaction